# How to determine the $k$ value when an expression has exactly two solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I have an expression (an even function) like this:

```
Log2[k x^2] - 2^Abs[x]
```

We can plot it by using [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html),

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Log2[k x^2] - 2^Abs[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}], {k, 
  2, 4}]
```

[image]

As we can see, when $k$ is approximately 3.1, the expression has two solutions. But how can we calculate this value of $k$ exactly?

#### Current try:

Guess an initial solution, such as 3, that is smaller than the real solution.

```
sol=FindRoot[Log2[3x^2]-2^Abs[x],{x,1}]
(* {x->1.48605} *)

Solve[Log2[k x^2]==2^Abs[x]/.sol,k]
(* {{k->3.15632}} *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real values of `x`, `Abs[x] == Sqrt[x^2]`. This form is required for the derivative to be defined.

```
f[k_, x_] = Log2[k x^2] - 2^Sqrt[x^2];
```

You want the `{x, k}` values for which both the function and its derivative are zero.

```
eqns = {f[k, x] == 0, D[f[k, x], x] == 0};
```

The exact solutions are expressed in terms of [`ProductLog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html)

```
(sol = Solve[eqns, {x, k}, Reals]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(*  {{True, True}, {True, True}}  *)
```

The approximate numerical values are

```
sol // N

(*  {{x -> -1.48605, k -> 3.15632}, {x -> 1.48605, k -> 3.15632}}  *)
```

Comment: Perfect~~~~~ :)

Answer (score 4):

Start with

```
Simplify[k /. ToRules[Reduce[D[Log2[k x^2]-2^Abs[x],x]==0 && 
 Log2[k x^2]-2^Abs[x]==0 && x>0, {x, k}]]]
```

which tells you that k is exactly (2^E^ProductLog[2/Log[2]]*Log[2]^2)/ProductLog[2/Log[2]]^2

but I am not certain that is a particularly rewarding answer.

Checking that with N says it is approximately 3.1563220300507372963 so it seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve in two steps. As $\log_2(k x^2)=\log_2(k)+\log_2(x^2)$ the value of x where derivative vanishes of the desired function is independent of k.  Just considering $x>0$, given the symmetry,then solving  $log_2(k {x_v}^2) -2^{x_v}=0$ for $k$ yields the result ($x_v$ is x value where derivative vanishes).

```
f[k_, x_] := Log2[k x^2] - 2^x
xv = x /. Solve[D[f[k, x], x] == 0, x][[1]]
k /. Solve[f[k, xv] == 0, k][[1]] // TraditionalForm
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Log2[k x^2], 2^Abs[x], f[k, Abs@x]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {-15, 10}, GridLines -> {{-xv, xv}, None}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (f[k, Abs[#]] &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], {k, 1, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]